# Using virtualbox port forwarding with ports <1024 and authbind with linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm trying to use Virtualbox to separate the services on my machine into their own VM. To achieve this it would be helpful if I could set up port-forwarding from the host to the guests. (using network-bridges is NOT an option).

I know that this is not possible when running virtualbox as non-root user on linux without additional software.

Now I wonder if authbind might help.

Does anybody already have some experience with this setup?

(The services are: http/https, smtp and dns)

Comment: It seems that the idea of using authbind was not good. I'll try with iptables port forwarding on the host as next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve my goal.

The solution was to *abandon authbind* and also the virtualbox port forwarding and to use *host-only network* in virtualbox in combination with *1:1 NAT via iptables*.